# Does cassandra clusters need extra configuration on docker-compose file to connect three nodes on a single cluster?

Tags: docker, cassandra

i am currently trying to set up a cassandra cluster with three nodes, but the correct functionality of it is estochastic, every time i set up the docker-compose file, a replicant node doesnt appear at the moment i use the nodetool status. Am i doing something bad on the file or is it something with cassandra that must be improved?

Edit: forgot to mention i tried this docker compose file on Windows and in Ubuntu LTS

here is the docker-compose.yml that i am using:

```
version: '3'
services:
# The first node and config in the first datacenter.
    node1:
        image: cassandra:latest
        container_name: coordinatorNode
        hostname: node1
        networks:
            dc1ring:
                ipv4_address: 172.30.0.2
        volumes:
            - ./musicdb:/opt/dse/musicdb
        environment:
            # - DS_LICENSE=accept
            # - SEEDS=node1
            # - START_RPC=false
            # - CLUSTER_NAME=dse51_cluster
            - CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=172.30.0.2
            # - NUM_TOKENS=3
            # - DC=DC1
            # - RACK=RAC1
            # - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1000000000
            # - HEAP_NEWSIZE= 4096M
        expose:
            # Intra-node communication
            - 7000
            # TLS intra-node communication
            - 7001
            # JMX
            - 7199
            # CQL
            - 9042
            # CQL SSL
            - 9142
        ports:
            - 9042:9042
        ulimits:
            memlock: -1
            nproc: 32768
            nofile: 100000
        restart: always
    node2:
        image: cassandra:latest
        container_name: replicantNode1
        hostname: node2
        networks:
            dc1ring:
                ipv4_address: 172.30.0.3
        volumes:
            - ./musicdb:/opt/dse/musicdb
        environment:
            # - DS_LICENSE=accept
            - SEEDS=node1
            # - START_RPC=false
            # - CLUSTER_NAME=dse51_cluster
            - CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=172.30.0.3
            - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=172.30.0.2,172.30.0.4
            # - NUM_TOKENS=3
            # - DC=DC1
            # - RACK=RAC1
#            - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1000000000
#            - HEAP_NEWSIZE= "4G"
        expose:
            - 7000
            - 7001
            - 7199
            - 9042
            - 9142
        ports:
            - 9043:9042
        ulimits:
            memlock: -1
            nproc: 32768
            nofile: 100000
        depends_on:
            - node1
        restart: always
    node3:
        image: cassandra:latest
        container_name: replicantNode2
        hostname: node3
        networks:
            dc1ring:
                ipv4_address: 172.30.0.4
        volumes:
            - ./musicdb:/opt/dse/musicdb
        environment:
            # - DS_LICENSE=accept
            - SEEDS=node1
            # - START_RPC=false
            # - CLUSTER_NAME=dse51_cluster
            - CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=172.30.0.4
            - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=172.30.0.2,172.30.0.3
            # - NUM_TOKENS=3
            # - DC=DC1
            # - RACK=RAC1
            # - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1000000000
            # - HEAP_NEWSIZE= "4G"
        expose:
            - 7000
            - 7001
            - 7199
            - 9042
            - 9142
        ports:
            - 9044:9042
        ulimits:
            memlock: -1
            nproc: 32768
            nofile: 100000
        depends_on:
            - node1
        restart: always

networks:
    dc1ring:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.30.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the challenge with deploying multi-node clusters on Docker is getting the networking right. If I were to guess, I'd say you're running into one of 2 problems:

1. nodes cannot gossip with each other
2. containers are running into a port conflict

You need to make sure that all [the necessary ports used by Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/configuration/secureFireWall.html) are exposed between each nodes.

You also need to make sure that the local ports mapped to container ports are not already in use by another container. For example, use CQL port `9041` and gossip port `7001` for node 1, `9042` + `7002` for node 2, and so on.

If you just want to try using Cassandra on a laptop, have a look at [DataStax Desktop](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsdesktop/doc/desktop/dsDesktopAbout.html) (free to use). It allows you deploy Cassandra in Docker containers without the hassle of manually setting it up.

There's also [K8ssandra.io](https://dtsx.io/3znMa05) -- our opinionated deployment of Cassandra on Kubernetes (fully open-source and free) using the [cass-operator](https://github.com/k8ssandra/cass-operator) and with all the admin tools already bundled in:

- [Reaper](http://cassandra-reaper.io/docs/) for automated repairs
- [Medusa](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa/wiki) for backups and restores
- [Metrics Collector](https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra) for monitoring with Prometheus + Grafana
- Traefik templates for k8s cluster ingress
- [Stargate.io](https://dtsx.io/2XHbiRo) - a data gateway for connecting to Cassandra using REST API, GraphQL API and JSON/Doc API

Finally if you just want to build apps for Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier that doesn't require a credit card and you can launch a Cassandra cluster in just 5 clicks.

Comment: as much i like datastax, because i started to experiment there with Cassandra, this is for a college work that is forcing me to use plain cassandra, sadly is explicit the requirement of not using services like Astra or Datastax

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, both DataStax Desktop and K8ssandra deploy open-source Cassandra. The only difference is the ease of deployment, not the C* distribution. Cheers!